# What can I do to get better overlap in propensity score distributions?

Tags: causality, assumptions, propensity-scores, confounding

I would like to verify the positivity assumption to identify causal effects from observational data. My exposure prevalence is about 6%. When I included several potential confounders in my exposure model and checked density plots for areas of overlap between the exposed and unexposed, I got peaks at 1.0 for the unexposed and near 0 for the unexposed, with nothing in the middle. I then restricted the covariate set based on lasso regression and get similar results. I finally restricted the covariate set to the variable I think is most likely to confound the exposure and the outcome. I got propensities from 0 to about 0.95 for the exposed and 0.95 to 1 for the unexposed. Long story short, I am getting no overlap in propensity scores despite having a theory-based approach to confounder selection and several backups to that approach.

I know the covariate set should not consist of instruments and should consist of only true confounders (cause both exposure and outcome). Does anyone know what to do in this situation? Does exposure prevalence matter here? I noticed that as the exposure becomes common over time(around 20%), I have a good overlap of propensity scores at later time points using a large set of covariates.

Any advice would be helpful!

Comment: I would guess one or more of your covariates almost perfectly predicts treatment, meaning it is impossible to get overlap and your causal question fundamentally cannot be answered by confounding control methods without making strong assumptions about functional form. When you run a logistic regression model of treatment on your covariates, what do the results look like? Are there covariates with huge standardized coefficients? When looking at the covariate distributions, are there any that are particularly imbalanced prior to adjustment?

Comment: Do you have a causal graph of your variables?

Comment: @AdrianKeister I am not allowed to export anything from the virtual data enclave in which I am conducting the analyses. I'm also not sure how to reproduce this example.

Comment: In my opinion, the causal graph (a directed acyclic graph), showing which variables cause which (if $X$ causes $Y$, you draw $X\to Y$), and analyzing the main causal path for variables that set up a backdoor path (the true definition of confounder), is the best way to go.

Comment: @Noah I checked the main covariates' distributions and many from the larger set are highly prevalent and many are not. From the smaller set, the prevalences are very low. No doubt that is leading to a sparse cell count. What are the strong assumptions about functional form you're referring to? I am using a SuperLearner library with five algorithms in the ltmle package in R to try to get around making assumptions about the exposure's and the outcome's functional forms.

Comment: @Alex I'm referring to the idea that you should skip propensity scores and just use outcome regression. The functional form assumption is that the potential outcome models for the two potential outcomes are the same. If this assumption is true, it doesn't matter that you don't have overlap, and you can just use the outcome model to extrapolate. This is highly not recommended because the assumptions are quite strict and basically impossible to justify.

Comment: @Alex regarding the problem you're asking about, it seems like you have perfect predictions of your propensity scores. A DAG won't help you solve that unless it's possible you are accidentally including post-treatment variables or instruments. Again, all I can say is that if your groups are fundamentally different from each other, you simply cannot use propensity score methods, and if you use outcome regression, you have to make strict assumptions about functional form. These are not the only statistical methods you can use to estimate causal effects, though.